# Get variable value from PHP file using JQuery/AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I just want to do the simple thing: on click get a variable value from the php file a display it on my page.
E.g.

```
<div class="click" onclick="getMyValue()">Click me</>

<script>
function getMyValue() {
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "basket_count.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res['item_count']);
            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("Error");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

basket_count.php

```
$item_count = 3;
echo json_encode($item_count);
```

Not working though. I'm getting "Error" in my console.log();

UPD: 
I've tried to add this to error: `error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);}`

Below is the message i'm getting:
[image]

UPD: 
Nothing was wrong with the code, the issue was that I was including "header.php" in my php file, so there was some conflict with it. I removed it and it started to work just fine.

Comment: what error you got?

Comment: Also post your `getMyValue()` code

Comment: Write AJAX code in `getMyValue` function, I cannot see `getMyValue` function defined in your code.

Comment: can you also try :
error: function(res) {
      console.log(res);
}

Comment: In your PHP try `$result['item_count'] = 3; echo json_encode($result);` and in your ajax `console.log(res.item_count);`

Comment: @Nico_ I've tried it and it's giving me `Uncaught ReferenceError: res is not defined`

Comment: @MickaelLeger done that, same `Uncaught ReferenceError: res is not defined`

Comment: TRY this: `error: function(err) { console.log(err); }`

Comment: @kulan Well, this error mean you are in your "success" part, still a good point. Try to change res by "response" just to see if the error change?

Comment: @MickaelLeger `{readyState: 4, setRequestHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, getResponseHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}`

Comment: @MickaelLeger inside `status:200`, `statusText: 'Ok'` But after that I get "Error" message from console.log("Error). What gives, if status = ok?

Comment: In your success so, try this : `console.log(response.item_count);` after you did `$result['item_count'] = 3; echo json_encode($result);` in your php, what do you get?

Comment: And in you error try what @SalimIbrogimov wrote in comment to know the nature of your error

Comment: @MickaelLeger: Beg a pardon?

Comment: Sorry I was talking to OP, wrong @ ! I asked him to do what you asked him to do to check the nature of his error

Comment: @MickaelLeger I've attached image showing message.

Comment: @MickaelLeger Nothing was wrong with the code, the issue was that i was including "header.php" in me php file, so there was some conflict with it. I removed it and it started to working just fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad your manage to solve your issue !

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="click" onclick="getMyValue()">Click me</>

<script>

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "basket_count.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data:{get:"item_count"};
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res.responseText);
            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log("Error");
        }
    });
</script>
```

and in php add this :

```
if($_POST['get']==item_count){
 echo $item_count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things here if you need to fetch variable value directly from php file then alert(res); you will get 3 in alert.

You have used echo json_encode($item_count); instead make array with key and pass it to json encode.
echo json_encode(array("item_count" => $item_count));
you will get 3 with console.log(res['item_count']);